# ¿Como hacer referencia a un valor autonumérico en SQL?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Estoy haciendo un programa en Visual Basic con Visual Studio para manejar una base de datos en ACCESS

El problema es que esta base de datos tiene en todas las tablas un campo con un valor autonumérico que sirve de clave primaria.

Lo que quiero es hacer referencia a el desde Visual Basic, es decir, en la sentencia `SELECT`, al meter el valor he probado con `String`, `Integer` y `Long`, pero con todos ellos salta la excepción:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No coinciden los tipos de datos en
>   la expresión de criterios.'

Mi sentencia `SELECT` es algo asi:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value='" & PId & "';
```

Donde `PId` es la variable que os decia. He probado con los 3 tipos y ninguno funciona.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y pon el código completo que estas intentando, solo con la select no podemos apreciar el problema

Comment: Solo para verficar, podrias poner el describe de la tabla? (como estan definidos los campos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese no es el problema que estas teniendo. tu problema reside en tu consulta:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value='" & PId & "';"
```

Va a construir por ejemplo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value='32';
```

y esta mal, porque como bien dijiste, el valor es numerico, y en las consultas los valores numericos van sin comillas simples.

En tu App, el valor debe estar definido como int, eso es correcto. En la consulta, debes consultarlo como:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value=" & PId
```

(en access los ; al final tampoco aportan nada)

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó.